# Numerical if statement in a Bash Script using $'s

Tags: bash

I have written a short Bash Script:

```
   for j in 0 1 2 3 4 5
   do
       for (( i=$j; i <= 5; i++ ));
       do
           if [ $(($(($i - $j)) > 1)) ]; then
               echo "True" 
           else
               echo  "False"
           fi
       done
   done
```

I expect this script to output a mixture of Trues and Falses however it only outputs Trues. I have checked and seen that $(($(($i - $j)) > 1)) is correctly producing 0s and 1s as it is supposed to but apparently the if statement is not registering these and always assumes "True".

Am I missing something in my code?

Thank you very much

James

Comment: `$(($(($i - $j)) > 1))` wut?         Try this `(( i - j > 1)) `

Comment: `if (( i - j > 1 )); then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is checking `if [ 0 ]` and `if [ 1 ]` which isn't what you think. It will always return true because it is checking that the length of the string `0` and `1` is not zero.

Change it to:

```
for j in {0..5}
do
    for (( i=j; i<=5; i++ ))
    do
        if (( i - j > 1 ))
        then
            echo True
        else
            echo False
        fi
    done
done
```

Note that the use of the `$` prefix for variables within `((...))` is optional.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `if` incorrectly, you're testing for string length when you want an arithmetic comparison:

```
for j in {0..5}; do
    for i in $(seq $j 5); do
        if (( i - j > 1 )); then
            echo "True"
        else
            echo "False"
        fi
    done
done
```